# Adding up unique list combinations of a list of lists including int and str values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations, sublist

I have a list of sublists containing the name of a person and 4 characteristics that are measured in two-digit numbers. The list looks like this

```
stud_lst=[['Pete', '36', '36', '36', '30'], ['Derek', '31', '21', '31', '20'], ...]
```

Now I want to pair the people up and combine their characteristics in groups of 2 and 3. So I need each unique combination of every sublist while the sublist items are added up.

Example: I need the following new sublist `['PeteDerek', '67', '57', '67', '50']` for all people in the database as well as `['PeteDerekTommy' ...]`

I thought about

1. list slicing to get all names, pair them with
   `itertools.combinations` and append the initial list "stud_lst".
2. I could do the same with the numeric list slices and add them up
   with `zip` in a `for` loop.
   But then I get stuck with matching appropriately. Also, this is a lot of code and I feel like this is not very pythonic

Are there any libraries that can help or a smarter approach?

Comment: Using a python dictionary would likely make this whole process much easier. Hard to help you out further with little info on what your doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a generator which relies on [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```py
from functools import reduce
import itertools as it


def combine_all(people):
    for r in range(2, len(people)+1):
        for combination in it.combinations(people, r):
            yield reduce(combine_two, combination)


def combine_two(a, b):
    a_name, *a_attr = a
    b_name, *b_attr = b
    return [f'{a_name}{b_name}', *[f'{int(x)+int(y)}' for x, y in zip(a_attr, b_attr)]]


from pprint import pprint
pprint(list(combine_all(stud_lst)))
```